# How to get data from a sqllite database and store it in ListView

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a data base I need to read data from it and view it in a list view it contain some tables from them a table named "main_categories" which has one field called "category_name" which is the primary key
this is the DataAdapter:

```
    public DataAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public DataAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        try {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public DataAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        try {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor getTestData() {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";

            Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (mCur != null) {
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
            return mCur;
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>" + mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the DataBaseHelper:

```
    public  class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
        //destination path (location) of our database on device
        private static String DB_PATH = "";
        private static String DB_NAME ="my_knowledge";// Database name
        private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
        private final Context mContext;

        public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? Its database Version
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
                DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
            }
            else
            {
                DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
            }
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            //If the database does not exist, copy it from the assets.

            boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
            if(!mDataBaseExist)
            {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                this.close();
                try
                {
                    //Copy the database from assests
                    copyDataBase();
                    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
                }
                catch (IOException mIOException)
                {
                    throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
                }
            }
        }

        //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
        private boolean checkDataBase()
        {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
            return dbFile.exists();
        }

        //Copy the database from assets
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int mLength;
            while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
            {
                mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
        }

        //Open the database, so we can query it
        public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
        {
            String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
            mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            return mDataBase != null;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close()
        {
            if(mDataBase != null)
                mDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        }
    }

and this is the main activity for now:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private static String DB_NAME ="my_knowledge"; // Database name

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.main_list);
        DataAdapter mDbHelper = new DataAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();

        Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData();
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

I want to know a way to store the data in the tables of the array (for example "main_categories") and view them with the list view

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your table column type

```
List<String> temp;
testdata.moveToFirst();
do {
      temp.add(testdata.getString(0));
} while (testdata.moveToNext());
```

Your cursor `testdata` has the first row in `testdata.moveToFirst();` and each column is associated with column index i.e. 0, 1 etc.
`testdata.moveToNext();` will have successive rows.

Comment: the app crashed and the log says "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table , while compiling"

Comment: "No such table"; ensure that the table you're calling in your sql query exists.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- First of, I would consider adding a `query` method to your `DataBaseHelper` class instead of using a `rawQuery`, something like:

  `Cursor query(String table, String[] projection, String where, String orderBy) {
      return getReadableDatabase().query(table, projection, where, null, null, null, orderBy);
  }`
- You can call the query method inside `mDbHelper.getTestData()` and use the `Cursor` object to populate your list.
- Take a look at using a [Cursor Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html)?
  to do get the data out of the cursor and into your adapter.